# SSMS Parameter with multiple values including NULLs, but NULLs are always included in results even when not selected

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssms, isnull, multiple-value

I am trying to build an SSRS report with a parameter for File Note Type. The result set has rows with file notes and rows without file notes, so I want the user to be able to select all file note types, one or more types, or cases with no file notes in place.

I have used ISNULL, and have included an item in the parameter for NULLs which is '-'

No matter what I select in my report I always see NULL rows. i.e.) If I choose File Note Type "Billing Note" then I get the billing note rows **and NULL rows**. I suspect I've put the ISNULL in the wrong place, but this is more advanced coding than I'm used to and would be really grateful for some assistance.
I thought it might have been an SSRS issue so I tested it back in SSMS and have the same problem there. For the purposes of testing I have declared a File Note Type of 'SF' but the problem remains whichever type I declare or choose in SSRS via the parameter.

Many thanks.

```
DECLARE @FNOTE nvarchar(10) = 'SF';
DECLARE @REPDATE date = '20200318';


SELECT DISTINCT
[dbo].[CR_RefMaster].[RefCode] AS [MF_Code],
STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', '+'('+[dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[CatDesc]+') '+'['+[dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[AdminAssignName]+'] '+[dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[Index]+' - '+[dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[Note] AS [text()]
            FROM [dbo].[CR_FileNotes]
            WHERE [dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[EntCode] = [dbo].[CR_RefMaster].[RefCode] AND ISNULL([dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[Category],'-') IN (@FNOTE) 
            ORDER BY [dbo].[CR_FileNotes].[Index]
            For XML PATH(''),type
            ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        , 1, 2, '') AS [File_Notes]

FROM
[dbo].[B_InvList]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT
[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[ProformaNr] AS [ProformaNr],
(SUM([dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[BaseAmount]-[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[ChargesBase]+[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[WriteOffBase]-[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[ExchangeDif])) AS [PaidTotal]
FROM
[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts]
WHERE
(CONVERT(date,[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[DateVoucher])) <= @REPDATE
GROUP BY
[dbo].[BR_InvReceipts].[ProformaNr]
) AS [Receipts] ON [dbo].[B_InvList].[ProformaNr] = [Receipts].[ProformaNr]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CR_RefMaster] ON [dbo].[B_InvList].[RefCode] = [dbo].[CR_RefMaster].[RefCode]
WHERE
(CONVERT(date,[dbo].[B_InvList].[DateInvoice])) <= @REPDATE
AND 
([dbo].[B_InvList].[InvoiceBase] - (ISNULL([Receipts].[PaidTotal],0)) <> 0)


/*FILENOTE LOOKUP*/
SELECT
'-' AS [Value],
'-' AS [Label]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
[dbo].[LookValues].[Name] AS [Value],
[dbo].[LookValues].[Name] AS [Label]
FROM
[dbo].[LookValues]
WHERE
[dbo].[LookValues].[TabCode] = 'MEMT'
AND [dbo].[LookValues].[InUse] = '1'
ORDER BY [Label]
```

Here is an example of the results:
[Sample results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CONth.png)

Comment: Without knowing all the table structures and some sample data it's hard to spot what's wrong. It sort of looks OK just reading it...   Although this won't solve why your code does not work now, you could try moving the where clause from inside STUFF and moving it alongside the date check e.g. ` AND ISNULL([File_Notes], '-') IN (@FNOTE)`

Comment: Thanks, I have included a snip of results by way of edit to original post.  If I were to move the ISNULL outside of STUFF I would need to JOIN that table too I believe? I tried that but no joy. Also couldn't get my head around whether I'd need an inner or outer join in that scenario! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you will need to change any joins, just add `AND ISNULL([File_Notes], '-') IN (@FNOTE)` to the final where clause after `([dbo].[B_InvList].[InvoiceBase] - (ISNULL([Receipts].[PaidTotal],0)) <> 0)`

Comment: Invalid column name 'File_Notes'...

Comment: I'll take another look in the morning, brain dead now it's 10.20pm here.